# GPS inaccurate due to leap second

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I have my app running on rooted android phones running 6.0.1. These phones are planted in automobiles which are running across the country rendering them inaccessible, so upgrading to Android 7 is out of question (mostly because many of my app's features need to be retested and the life of the product is just 1 month more, so not worth the effort). Since January, I have noticed inaccurate GPS readings. Apparently, I need to update the almanac, but I am not sure how do I do that programmatically.

Below code didn't work for me:

```
locationManager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, "delete_aiding_data", null);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);
```

All the 3 APIs above returned True. In logs, I just found this:

> E/virtual loc_api_adapter_err
>   LocApiV02::deleteAidingData(GpsAidingData):940]: error! status =
>   eLOC_CLIENT_SUCCESS, delete_resp.status = eQMI_LOC_ENGINE_BUSY_V02

I have the following permission in manifest - android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Please let me know, if you need any more info.

Comment: Do you have the following permission in your manifest - android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS?

Comment: Yes I have. Edited the question. Thanks for looking into it.